# Debian gluster install doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-20.04, glusterfs

Following the [instructions](https://docs.gluster.org/en/main/Install-Guide/Install/) to add the gluster PPA to my Ubuntu 20.04 system, I get the following error when doing the `apt update` command:

```
Ign:5 https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/Debian/11/amd64/apt ocal InRelease
Err:6 https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/Debian/11/amd64/apt ocal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 8.43.85.185 443]
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'https://download.gluster.org/pub/gluster/glusterfs/LATEST/Debian/11/amd64/apt ocal Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

This seems to be the problem with every version of their repository I can find.   Can someone tell me if this is supposed to work on Ubuntu 20.04.4 and if so is there a workaround?

**UPDATE**:  It turns out that Canonical has a set of gluster packages in their repository that work so I am using that.  However I would still like to know if the maintainers of gluster have something to update or I had erred in the procedure.

Comment: I'm confused by your post title: Are you following the Debian or the Ubuntu instructions for your Ubuntu server?

Comment: @MikaelH There are no "Ubuntu" instructions that I am aware of.  The link I have has instructions for a Debian system, and the system I am installing on is and Ubuntu system.    However it turns out Canonical has put a working set of gluster packages in their repository so I am just using those.

Comment: The Ubuntu instructions are right below the Debian ones on the page you linked. But if you’re good to go with the packages supplied directly with the distro that’s fine too, of course.